# Mule 4 : Is there a way to refer Maven POM properties from a Mule Flow?

Tags: mule4

I want to refer the project name and version in the URL of the API. For example, my app is called **sample-mule-project** and has a version **"v1"**. So my final URL should be like **/sample-mule-project/v1/**

Maven pom has these properties called name and version with which we can refer these values inside the pom file. Is there a way how we can refer these values inside the mule flow?

I tried using **${project.name}** and **${project.version}** but it did not work which I understand is because these are not defined inside properties file. So is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Maven properties do not exists anymore when the application is executed.

You can use some Maven plugins to replace values in a properties files, that can be used inside the application. For example the [Maven Resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). Be careful of not override properties inside other files, like the XML Mule configurations of the application.