# How can I access POM file properties inside mule configuration files?

Tags: pom.xml, mulesoft, mule4

Lets say I needed to access a groupId inside the properties tag of my POM file. How can i access that in my mule configuration file.

I tried to access it like ${pom.properties.app.groupId} but it didn't work. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked before at [Mule 4 : Is there a way to refer Maven POM properties from a Mule Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62118433/mule-4-is-there-a-way-to-refer-maven-pom-properties-from-a-mule-flow?rq=1) and probably others.

I'll repeat my answer here because Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to mark this one as a duplicate.

> That's because Maven properties do not exists anymore when the
> application is executed.
>
> You can use some Maven plugins to replace values in a properties
> files, that can be used inside the application. For example the
> [Maven Resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). Be careful of not override properties inside other
> files, like the XML Mule configurations of the application.

Update: I have created an example:

Assume that you have a properties file called config.properties in which you want to put the value of Maven property `name`:

```
a=1
b=${some.property}
```

Then you can enable Maven property filtering in just that file with:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>config.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>     
    </resources>
    ...
```

My blog has a longer explanation of this example: https://medium.com/@adobni/using-maven-properties-as-mule-properties-3f1d0db62c43

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One request. Can you able to point me to a example project for this please.

Comment: I have added an example